# Передать List<Model> с помощью socket

Tags: c#, wcf

Как можно передать `List <ElementModel>` с помощью socket?

```
class ElementModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Brush Color { get; set; }
    Thickness Margin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно именно на таком низком уровне работать ? Быть может вам подойдет [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) там все значительно проще. Ну, а если нет, то вам сюда [сокеты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Сериализуйте и передавайте удобным для вас способом.

Comment: Ваш вопрос, вроде, никак не связан с GUI, поэтому уберите метку wpf. | Почему стоит метка wcf? Вы используете именно эту технологию? Вы пишете wcf-сервис или wcf-клиент?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov отправляю с клиента на сервер данные. Хотелось узнать как можно отравить List

Comment: Это должно быть описано в описании сервиса. Есть wsdl?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  нет

Comment: Тогда вопрос не имеет решения. Ведь неизвестно, как вообще работать с этим сервисом.